# Definition of an integral

Tags: integration, definition

To compute the area under a curve. We need to take every point where the function is defined and sum up all the tiny line we obtain. This is $$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

We are summing up tiny rectangles of height $f(x)$ and width $dx$. But because there are infintely many points in the interval $[a,b]$ and because a point has no width, we can't sum up all of them or we will obtain of result of $\infty$. That's why we sum up with a width of $dx$. But by doing that we are not really precise on the computation, this is not the smallest measurment possible, we have a roundness error right ?

The correct way (for me) of defining an integral should be : 
$$\lim_{\text{dx}\rightarrow0}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Comment: What you've given is (sorta) the "spirit" of the integral, but not the actual definition.  The definition takes care of all these fuzzy bits.

Comment: Is it : how the integral behaves to small changement h (the derivative of the integral) is just f(x), the curve we are integrating, this is the powerful link and this is where we are able to compute mathematically the value of it right ? This is insane! The function that describes the area under the curve f behaves like the function itself. We are not finding the deriative of the function but we are looking for a function which derivative is the actual function!

Comment: Although this is explained repeatedly in this community, the answer is simple: $dx$ in the integral sign is a formal symbol, rather than an actual infinitesimal quantity. So the notation is sound. The technical complexity of realizing differentials belies the conceptual simplicity of them, and so, it is totally safe to regard the expression $\int_{\square}^{\square} \cdots \, \mathrm{d}\square$ as a whole at this point. In the course of more advanced mathematics, one has chances to learn how to define $\mathrm{d}x$ as a standalone object, either as differential-form or as measure.

Comment: I see where you're going with this, but remember you can't define something with that something itself. For example what use is it if I say: $e = \sqrt{e^2}$I think what you are trying to say is the definition of an integral should be $$\int_a^b{f(x)dx} = \lim_{\triangle x \rightarrow 0}{\sum_{j = 1}^\infty{f(x_j)\triangle x}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will walk you through a somewhat informal derivation of the Riemann integral.

Basically, you want to cut up an area into a bunch of tiny rectangles then add their areas.

So think of some function $f(x)$ which is continuous on $[a,b]$. Then let $$I=\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx$$
Our goal is to approximate this really well. To do so, we cut up $[a,b]$ into $n$ segments of equal length, and call each one of these segments $S_i=[\alpha_i,\beta_i]$ for integer $0\leq i\leq n$. Also we will want to define $\beta_i=\alpha_{i+1}$, and $\alpha_i<\beta_i$.

Thus $\text{length}(S_i)=\frac{b-a}n$.

We then make a rectangle with base $S_i$ and height $f(\beta_i)$. Call these rectangles $R_i$. So, it makes since that 
$$I\approx \sum_{i=0}^{n}\text{Area}(R_i)$$
When we recall that $\text{Area}(R_i)=\text{base}(R_i)\cdot\text{height}(R_i)=\frac{b-a}nf(\beta_i)$ (because $R_i$ is a rectangle), we have that 
$$I\approx \sum_{i=0}^n\frac{b-a}nf(\beta_i)=\frac{b-a}n\sum_{i=0}^nf(\beta_i)$$
Then we recall that by definition $\alpha_0=a$, $\beta_n=b$, and $\beta_i-\alpha_i=\frac{b-a}n$, we have that $$\beta_i=a+\frac{i}n(b-a)$$
So we have that 
$$I\approx \frac{b-a}n\sum_{i=0}^nf\bigg(a+\frac{i}n(b-a)\bigg)$$
And the larger we make $n$, the more rectangles there will be, thus the better our approximation of $I$ will be. Or more formally,
$$I=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}n\sum_{i=0}^nf\bigg(a+\frac{i}n(b-a)\bigg)$$
and hence the *definition* of the definite Riemann integral:
$$\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}n\sum_{i=0}^nf\bigg(a+\frac{i}n(b-a)\bigg)$$
As you mentioned, the approximation of an integral with a sum is rarely (if ever) going to be perfect. This it to be expected. Which is *why* the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is there. The limit ensures the equality of the integral and the sum. Then integral is an exact value, and the sum approaches it.

I hope this helped.